# Integrating a custom launcher into the Visual Studio Debugger

Tags: visual-studio-debugging, visual-studio-extensions

We're creating a Visual Studio Debugger extension that needs to launch the application being debugged through a custom launcher that sets up the runtime (not the CLR or Win32) and launch the target application in a new process.  In other words, the custom launcher is in charge of creating the new process.  In the VS Debugger, one typically launches the debugger by calling VsShellUtilities.LaunchDebugger() and supplying a VsDebugTargetInfo object whose dlo field is set to DEBUG_LAUNCH_OPERATION.DLO_CreateProcess, along with the coordinates of the exe file to be launched and debugged.  This doesn't conform to our launching model.

There is also a dlo value DEBUG_LAUNCH_OPERATION.DLO_Custom that seems to be for this purpose (using the clsIdCustom field to indicate the launcher), but the current documentation says that's obsolete and directs us back to DEBUG_LAUNCH_OPERATION.DLO_CreateProcess, but not only doesn't that fit our model, but clsidCustom is used in this case to indicate the debug engine (if it's just a single one).

So, what is the recommended way for us to launch the VS debugger and use our custom launcher to configure and start our runtime (and the application within it)?

Answer (score 2):

According to the Visual Studio API document, it only provide the [DLO_CreateProcess](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.shell.interop.debug_launch_operation(v=vs.140).aspx) to Launches the process. You could use dwClsidCount and pclsidList specify the debug engines to use.

Following example introduce how to call a custom launcher through a VSIX project.

https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Visual-Studio-Debug-Engine-c2e21c0e

Answer (score 0):

I'm having difficulty porting to a Modern VS2022 but I've been using the VSIX template built of of this Extension which works for VS2017 and VS2019.  after some tinkering.  This does work for VS2022 but only if you don't tamper with the packages.

https://github.com/microsoft/VSProjectSystem/blob/master/doc/extensibility/IDebugLaunchProvider.md  Good luck there's not a lot out there so I thought I'd offer you this gem.

This allows you to make a drop done selection for a project property sheets for debugging. you got to import the targets file which then imports the rules sheet that you create which means you got to make a wizard that creates a custom project.